# How to load external JSP taglib in Grails properly

Tags: grails, jsp-tags, taglib, smartclient

I'm trying to integrate Isomorphic SmartClient with Grails. SmartClient server has some custom JSP taglibs described with xml file (it's TLD file based on schema web-jsptaglibrary_1_1.dtd).

I have proper jars in classpath and just for a test two similar files in Grails application web-app directory. The first one is w00t.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/iscTaglib.xml" prefix="isc" %>
<html>
<body>
<pre>
    <isc:loadDMIStubs ID="ko" />
</pre>
<%= "w00t" %>
</body>
</html>
```

And the second one is dafaq.gsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/iscTaglib.xml" prefix="isc" %>
<html>
<body>
<pre>
    <isc:loadDMIStubs ID="ko" />
</pre>
<%= "dafaq" %>
</body>
</html>
```

When I'm loading those files through browser the JSP one works as expected and the tag is executed. However when I'm trying to call GSP file then an exception is thrown:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException
Unknown JSP tag isc:loadDMIStubs
```

According to Grails docs this should work, shouldn't it?